# Group geometries of line data based on one common attribute and compute length

Tags: qgis, postgis, vector, aggregation

I have a vector file of river networks in QGIS. Some of the rivers are split up it multiple rows. What I'd like to do is to aggregate the rivers based on the attribute in one column (`S_NAME`) and afterwards calculate the length of each aggregated river.

I know there must be some PostGIS commands to do that. I'd be fine with any pointer to anything that relates to it. The pseudo-code I have in my head would look something like this:

```
output = layer -> groupyby(S_NAME) -> st_distance(.)
```

I know this is really bad, but maybe someone has any idea:.

The link to the data (18k rows...) is here:
https://geoportal.bafg.de/inspire/download/reporting_units/riverWaterBodyForWFD/datasetfeed.xml

Answer (score 5):

The data is in EPSG:4258 - ETRS89 - Geographic, so the units aren't usable for length, etc.

You need to transform the geometry to something in units you can work with - meters, I'm guessing, so what the UTM zone in Germany that would be appropriate for this data still needs adding, but here is the SQL:

```
select
    r.s_name
    , ST_Length(ST_Transform(st_union(geom), ????)) as river_length
from
    public."RWBODY_DE" as r
group by
    r.s_name
```

Where ???? is of course the SRID of the cooredinate system in meters you'll use to get length in meters.

Answer (score 3):

You also could use the GUI.

Run `dissolve` on the river layer based on `S_NAME`, then use the field calculator to add the `$length` to each river. If your CRS is not suited for this, you need to save your layer to a fitting one first.